# Notification payload sent to APNS through HTTP/2 Request with status code 200

Tags: apple-push-notifications, http2

I'm trying to send 1000 notification payload to APNS server for the same device token. When my program sent out the notification payload to APNS, through http/2 and getting the response 200 for all my requests. And it confirms that the payload is sent to APNS server. However, the device cannot receive any notification, did i missed anything!

Thanks in advance...